# My application fails to launch in time

Tags: ios

My application is crashing. I have no clue as to what the cause of the crash is since it has only crashed two times in a month. Also in the device log I found the following message:

> Aug  3 11:26:28 unknown SpringBoard[15] : com.xyz.abe failed to launch in time
>
> Aug  3 11:26:28 unknown SpringBoard[15] : Forcing crash report of abc[392]...
>
> Aug  3 11:26:28 unknown SpringBoard[15] : Finished crash reporting.
>
> Aug  3 11:26:28 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] :
>    (UIKitApplication:com.xyz.abe[0x8558]) Exited: Killed: 9
>
> Aug  3 11:26:28 unknown SpringBoard[15] : Application 'abc' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
>   Aug  3 11:26:28 unknown ReportCrash[393] : Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/abc_2012-08-03-112628_DeviceName.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0

On searching the web, I found that this is because of doing heavy processing in 
"applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:" Please check my code and let me know what is wrong with the code.

Thanks!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
britenessView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
britenessView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
britenessView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
britenessView.alpha = 0.0;
StoreIPad *viewController = [[StoreIPad alloc] init];
nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];    
[self.window addSubview:nav.view];
[self.window addSubview:britenessView];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self)
{
    //iniatializing inAppPurchase
    InAppPurchase *inAppManager = [InAppPurchase sharedManager];
    inAppManager.inappDelegate = self;        
    subscriber = FALSE;        
}
return self;}
+ (InAppPurchase *)sharedManager{    // InAppPurchase sharedManager
@synchronized(self)
{
    if (!_sharedInstance)
    {
        _sharedInstance =  [[self alloc] init];
    }
}
return _sharedInstance;}-(id)init{ // InAppPurchase init

self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    isRestoring = NO;
    arrTransactions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return self;}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to "check your code" if you haven't provided any of it?

Comment: i have add my code, sorry for trouble

Comment: could you please add StoreIPad's init method as well? The problem seems to be in there.

Comment: Sorry, but the code doesn't obviously seem to be particularly slow. I don't know what's wrong.